# Devstack/Openstack Home lab on Ubuntu - [ VM's created on Ubuntu machine using Openstack are not accessible outside LAN]

Tags: devstack

I am setting up Devstack (Openstack) Home Lab set on ubuntu box and we creating VM's on same ubuntu machine where Openstack is installed. But the Internal IP's (10.0.02,.. ) 0r corresponding floating IP's (172.24.4.2,... ) are not accessible from other LAN machine's. How we can publish internal IP's to external LAN machines.

Regards
Rishi

Answer (score 0):

This is not enable for default. What I know is that vms can access all the machines, but outer would machines can't access internal vms. 
However, the head node of openstack can access any of you vms.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do on dashboard is following

1. Launch Instance
2. Associate Floating IP to the Instance
3. Check security profile and confirm the protocol you use is on the list (by default implicit deny all)

Please make sure "*q-l3*" and other neutron service is enabled in your *devstack/local.conf*.
if you can give us Open vSwitch information it will help.

```
$ sudo ovs-vsctl show 

    Bridge br-int
        Port ...
    Bridge br-ex
        Port "eth2"
            Interface "eth2"
        Port "qg-5d0d5dbd-99"
            Interface "qg-5d0d5dbd-99"
                type: internal
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
```